# Applying for f2 visa in last semester

Tags: f1-visas

I got married 2 months ago and I want to have my wife over. The problem is my current i20 says that my program will end in 2022 however once I apply for my opt my i20 will say that my program ends in May 2020.
I have two options either I apply for f2 visa with my current i20 and then apply for opt. In this case can there be a problem when my wife tries to enter USA using her updated i20 (which will say that program ends in May 2020) while her visa will expire at a later time. Will this difference create an issue at the time of entry?

The second option is that I can wait to get my EAD card and then apply for f2. However, what are my chances to get F2 Visa approved during OPT?

Comment: Questions about residence should be asked on our sister site [expatriates.se].